# How to get data table without using database name in query

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I tried to get table which has top record from Oracle database through ODBC driver. For this, I am using below code.

```
OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=localhost;Uid=system;Pwd=abc;Database = NORTHWIND";
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT \"NORTHWIND\".\"ORDERS\".\"ID\" AS \"My field id\" FROM \"NORTHWIND\".\"ORDERS\" WHERE ROWNUM = 1";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query,con);
        var k = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Load(k);
        con.Close();
```

The above code is working fine for me. I need to execute query without database name. Here database name is NORTHWIND. But If I am using query without database name like `"SELECT \"ORDERS\".\"ID\" AS \"My field id\" FROM \"ORDERS\" WHERE ROWNUM = 1"` 
I got an exception **"table or view does not exist."**

Even if my connectionstring has database name, I got this exception.

Can anyone explain me why I got the above exception when using query without database name?

Comment: I want to execute query like this. query = "SELECT ORDERS.ID AS My field id FROM ORDERS WHERE ROWNUM = 1";

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to this-

```
builder.ConnectionString = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=localhost;Uid=system;Pwd=abc;Data Source = NORTHWIND;";
```

Referrences-

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/
- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT199

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My problem is not resolved after changing the connecting string as you mentioned.  Can you please suggest me any other solution?

Comment: @KavithaM Please check the edited answer. Also check the last reference link.